# Location INformation from 3G Dongle android

Tags: android, android-location, android-usb

Currently I connected 3g Dongle with my tablet through USB data cable. I want to get location information such as latitude, longitude from that dongle network. Though My tablet doesn't have Network / GPS / bluetooth support. So I can't use and  by GPS_PROVIDER, NETWORK_PROVIDER and PASSIVE_PROVIDER not working. Basically I don't have idea in this, I want to know any library or example for that would be very grateful to me.

Please help me in this, Thanks in Advance...